# Restrict map panning to an area in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox-gl-js

I want the same behavior shown in [this Mapbox example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/restrict-bounds/) but using Leaflet 0.7.7 because of dependency on plugins not compatible with 1.0.

I know [maxBoundsViscosity option](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-panning-inertia-options) in Leaflet 1.0 and looks like Mapbox API uses it with value 1.0 to restrict the area.

Any change to implement this behavior in Leaflet 0.7.7? I need solid bounds without bouncing the user back like maxBounds option does.

Comment: Nope, there's no option that will do what you want in 0.7.7. However, the code affected by the `maxBoundsViscosity` option [is minimal](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v1.0.3/src/map/handler/Map.Drag.js#L150-L162) and if you only want solid bounds, it should be a pretty simple change to the [_onPreDrag](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v0.7.7/src/map/handler/Map.Drag.js#L94-L105) implementation of 0.7.7. If you absolutely must have that behaviour, forking it and making your own modification would be something to consider.